# Copy D3D11 Texture2D to D2D1 Bitmap

Tags: direct3d

I have a D3D11 device created, windows 10, latest edition, and a ID3D11Texture2D * created, GPU memory. I want to get the contents of this Texture2D stretched and drawn onto a region of an HWND. I don't want to use vertex buffers, I want to use "something else". I don't want to copy the bits down to the CPU, then bring them back up to GPU again. StretchDIBits or StretchBlt would be way too slow.

Let's pretend I want to use D2D1... I need a way to get my D3D11 texture2D copied or shared over to D2D1. Then, I want to use a D2D1 render target to stretch blit it to the HWND.

I've read the MS documents, and they don't make a lot of sense.
ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `ID3D11Texture`, why aren't you just using Direct3D to render it to a texture? That's what the hardware is designed to do very fast with high quality.

The [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures) `SpriteBatch` class is a good place to start for general sprite rendering, and it does indeed make use of  VBs, shader, etc. internally.

Direct2D is really best suited to scenarios where you are drawing classic vector/presentation graphics, like circles, ellipses, arcs, etc. It's also useful as a way to use DirectWrite for high-quality, highly scalable fonts. For blitting rectangles, just use Direct3D which is what Direct2D has to use under the covers anyhow.

Note that if you require Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 10.0 or better, you can use a common trick which relies on the `Vertex_ID`in the vertex shader, so you can self-generate the geometry without any need for a VB or IB. See [this code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Kits/ATGTK/FullScreenQuad).

Comment: The SpriteBatch was a fantastic answer. I don't want to use Direct3D to render it to a texture because the vertex buffer code, creating render targets, shader resource views, etc, is all "unmaintainable". The other people that have to work on this code aren't D3D experts, but they do understand a SpriteBatch.Blit( destinationRectangle ). I'm astonished it was so difficult to find the answer to how to stretch a Texture2D to a window, but at least there is an answer. Thanks.